# Ignore multiple results of a destructuring in typescript

Tags: typescript, tsc, destructuring, redeclaration

I'm using typescript destructuring as follows:

```
const props = new Map<User, [Name, Age, Location, Gender]>();
props.set(bill, [n, a, l, g]);

// ...

// Want to access location and gender of bill.
const [n, a, l, g] = props.get(bill);
console.log(l + g);
```

But this violates the `noUnusedLocals` compiler option, so what I really want is:

```
const [_, _, l, g] = props.get(bill);
```

but this violates a redeclaration of a block-scope variable (two variables named `_`).

What's the best way to deal with this? Perhaps destructuring is just the wrong choice here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the ES6 [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values) you can do it this way:

```
const [, , l, g] = props.get(bill);
```

You can find a minimal working example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20x%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20%5B%2C%20%2C%20y%5D%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A).